# Navbar will not touch the top

Tags: html, css

Hi I'm trying to get the multicoloured navbar to touch the very top of the screen with zero gap.  For some reason...there appears to be a 5px gap between the top of the screen and the navbar.

I've tried

`margin-top:0;`
`padding-top:0px;`  etc

[My JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/em0j490n/)

Please excuse the horrible colours...I was using them to try and identify any gaps.

Comment: try adding `body html head { margin:0px; padding:0px; }`.

Comment: @lal did you forget `,` characters between your selectors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the margin on your #session div and the body.

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/em0j490n/4/)**

```
#session {
    top:0;
    padding-top:0;
    position:relative;
    margin:0;
}
```

Comment: I need the margin in body to have it centred.

Comment: Having a margin on the body will cause a gap though. If you mean horizontally centered, set the body margin to `margin:0 auto;`. https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/em0j490n/5/

Answer (score 2):

its your ul #sessions id causing the problem, add a `margin:0;` to it and also a `margin-top:0;` to your body

```
#session {
  top: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  margin: 0; // add this
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: I need the margin in body to have it centred.  If I remove it...the content moves to the left.

Comment: margin-top does not effect your margin-left and right you have

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

```
#wrap {
    margin-top:-16px auto;
    height: 100%;
    width:100%
}
```

**or**

```
body {
        margin-top:-16px auto;
     }
```

[image]

Comment: That is in your webpage it is the default values given to the body different browsers handle these vaules differently, so you should slap the normalize.css before your own http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/